# how to center and bottom an button

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to CSS , can anyone help me with the layout. Below is the layout I have
[image]

I want the green button to be center and in the bottom of its container div (the white area) and I'm using flexbox. Below is my code:

```
//html

 <div className="box-layout">
        <div className="box-layout__box">
            <h1 className="box-layout__title">Expensify</h1>
            <p>It's time to get your expenses under control</p>
            <button className="button" onClick={startLogin}>Login with Google</button>
            <button className="button_anon" onClick={startLoginAnonymously}>Try it</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and css

```
.box-layout {
    background: url('/images/bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.box-layout__box{
    background: fade-out(white, .15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: $l-size $m-size;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25rem;
}

.button {
    background: $blue;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: $font-size-large;
    padding: $s-size;
}

.button_anon {
    background: green;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 0.8rem;

}
```

Comment: make your `.box-layout__box` your flexbox, not `.box-layout`. Flex items are the _immediate_ children of a flex container. Since it's the buttons you want to center they need to be your flex items

Answer (score 1):

I belive code below should do what you want

```
.box-layout__box{
    background: fade-out(white, .15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: $l-size $m-size;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[There](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is pretty nice article about flexbox and how to use it

Answer (score -1):

Try the code `<br>`right above the green button. It seems that it should be already centered. Otherwise wrap it around a div, and align the div to center.